# How do I tell awk not to make any changes to an empty row

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a dataset with three columns that look like this:

```
    0.1 0.2 0.3
    0.4 0.5 0.6

    0.7 0.8 0.9
    1.0 1.0 1.2
```

I want to subtract a certain number from each entry in the second column and I know how to do that. But with how the data looks, I end up getting an output that looks like this:

```
    0.1 0.1 0.3
    0.4 0.4 0.6
       -0.1
    0.7 0.7 0.9
    1.0 0.9 1.2
```

How do I prevent awk from adding that extra "-0.1" in the empty space?
I tried to use the sed command to remove that specific entry but since somewhere in the data, I have "-0.1" which must be in the data, it removes some important aspect of that data.

Comment: Can you show what the command you have now looks like?

Comment: gawk {'print $1, $2-2.7162, $3'} bands_down.xmgr > bands_down.xmgr_norm

Comment: Run the command on all lines except the 3rd. `awk 'NR != 3 { ..... }'`

Comment: thank you, that worked well, but in principle there can be many lines. 
I have found the answer from Cyrus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NF>0 {$2-=0.1}1' file
```

> `NF`: The number of fields in the current input record.

Output:

```
0.1 0.1 0.3
0.4 0.4 0.6

0.7 0.7 0.9
1.0 0.9 1.2
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)